# How to resolve IndexOutOfBoundException in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception, intellij-idea, while-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I tried to create a unique random name generator and order generator combing both and displaying text based on each name and order. But when I run my code multiple times I get the result without an error and at (CERTAIN) times it throws IndexOutOfBoundException. I am facing difficulty in pinpointing the origin of this exception as it points out to three different places in my code as marked by me with comment.

```
    import java.io.File

const val TAVERN_NAME = "Taernyl's Folly"
val patronList = mutableListOf("Eli", "Murdoch", "Sophie")
val lastName = listOf("IronFoot", "Fernsworth","Baggine ")
val uniqueNameSet = mutableSetOf<String>()
val menuList = File("data/tavern-menu-data.txt").readText().split("\n")

fun main() {
  
    generator()                                                      **//at TavernKt.main(Tavern.kt:15)**

}

private fun generator() {
    var orderCount = 0
    (0..9).forEach { _ ->
        val first = patronList.shuffled().first()
        val last = lastName.shuffled().first()
        val name = "$first $last"
        uniqueNameSet += name


    }
    println(uniqueNameSet)
    while (orderCount <= 9) {
        placeOrder(                                             //at TavernKt.generator(Tavern.kt:31)
            uniqueNameSet.shuffled().first(),
            menuList.shuffled().first()
        )
        orderCount++
    }
}

private fun placeOrder(patronName: String, menuData: String) {

    val indexOfApostrophe = TAVERN_NAME.indexOf('\'')
    val tavernMaster = TAVERN_NAME.substring(0 until indexOfApostrophe)
    println("$patronName \"speaks\"  with $tavernMaster about their Order.")
    val(type,name,price) = menuData.split(",")                  //at TavernKt.placeOrder(Tavern.kt:81)
    val message = "$patronName buys a $name($type) for $price."
    println(message)
    val phrase = if (name == "Dragon's Breath") {
        "$patronName exclaims: ${toDragonSpeak("Ah, delicious $name")}"
    } else {
        "$patronName says: Thanks for the $name"
    }
    println(phrase)

    //performPurchase(price)
}

private fun toDragonSpeak(phrase: String) =
    phrase.replace(Regex("[aeiou]")) {
        when (it.value) {
            "a" -> "4"
            "e" -> "3"
            "i" -> "1"
            "o" -> "0"
            "u" -> "|_|"
            else -> it.value
        }
    }
```

And this is my output:

```
[Eli Baggine , Sophie Fernsworth, Eli Fernsworth, Sophie IronFoot, Murdoch Fernsworth, Eli IronFoot]
Sophie Fernsworth "speaks"  with Taernyl about their Order.
Sophie Fernsworth buys a goblet of la croix(meal) for 1.22.
Sophie Fernsworth says: Thanks for the goblet of la croix
Murdoch Fernsworth "speaks"  with Taernyl about their Order.
Murdoch Fernsworth buys a shirley temple(elixir) for 4.12.
Murdoch Fernsworth says: Thanks for the shirley temple
Sophie Fernsworth "speaks"  with Taernyl about their Order.
Sophie Fernsworth buys a goblet of la croix(meal) for 1.22.
Sophie Fernsworth says: Thanks for the goblet of la croix
Eli IronFoot "speaks"  with Taernyl about their Order.
Eli IronFoot buys a Dragon's Breath(shandy) for 5.91.
Eli IronFoot exclaims: Ah, d3l1c10|_|s Dr4g0n's Br34th
Murdoch Fernsworth "speaks"  with Taernyl about their Order.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.base/java.util.Collections$SingletonList.get(Collections.java:4926)
    at TavernKt.placeOrder(Tavern.kt:81)
    at TavernKt.generator(Tavern.kt:31)
    at TavernKt.main(Tavern.kt:15)
    at TavernKt.main(Tavern.kt)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: In general you should not catch an IndexOutOfBoundsException, instead you should prevent it from occurring, by checking bounds before proceeding with an operation. In any case the problem is that `menuData.split(",")` produces only produces one item, which suggests it doesn't contain a comma-separated value (which BTW, also suggested you need to look for a more object-oriented approach). Please provide a [mre].

Comment: “it points out to three different places in my code” — you might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors).